# How to set date partition automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, partition, amazon-aurora

When I tried to create new table `table_new` by using DDL of existing table `table1`. To achieve this, following command returned its `DDL`.

`show create table table1`

Its `DDL` is at the bottom of the page, I'd like to set partition in `snapshot_date`.
and want to set them from `2022-01-01` to `2027-01-01` in each day. I tried to set them manually, but they take long time.

My question is

Are there any good way to achieve this?

What is `/*!50500` in following `DDL` ?

If someone has an opinion or materials, please let me know. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `table_new` (
   `snapshot_day` date NOT NULL,
   `A` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
   `B` char(10) NOT NULL,
   `C` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `INDEX` (`A`,`B`,`C`,`snapshot_day`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
 /*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(snapshot_day)
 (PARTITION p20220101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220102 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-02') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220103 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-03') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220104 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-04') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220105 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-05') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220106 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-06') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220107 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-07') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220108 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-08') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220109 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-09') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220110 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-10') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220111 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-11') ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20220112 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-12') ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Comment: I would use excel to generate the partition clauses as I'm not aware any built-in method for generating this - apart from using loops and string concatenation in a strored proc.

Comment: Read about the special comment syntax here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html